Smart Program test anchor


here in my instruction it need two things one is signer and other is a PDA account right? PIC 1
but in here while i'm testing i'm not able to pass the todoPda account as you can see it's showing some red squiggles. PIC 2
error is
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'todo_account' does not exist in type 'ResolvedAccounts<{ name: "signer"; writable: true; signer: true; } | { name: "todoAccount"; writable: true; pda: { seeds: [{ kind: "const"; value: [84, 79, 68, 79, 95, 65, 67, 67]; }, { kind: "account"; path: "signer"; }]; }; } | { ...; }>'

The Anchor TypeScript library automatically changes the Rust-style snake case to camel case so you have more conventional TypeScript variables. Try "todoAccount".

well in the latest anchor version there's no need to send it,but in previous anchor versions we need to send all accounts.
